# convert date format to diffrent date format like edm

Tags: java, date, datetime, edmx, datetimeoffset

Im having field type java.util.date and from it im getting the value of to.string()
Sat Sep 14 00:00:00 IDT 2013 but I need to get it in different format which is EDM format
like 2013-09-12T14:00  .
There is simple way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Simple way - `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: how ?im getting it from object and i cast it to Date ,how should i use the simple date format?

Comment: @JeanTennie  Can you guys let me know how I could do the same iusing javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` (a good tutorial is available [here](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-use-simpledateformat-class-formating-parsing-date-and-time/142)). Consider this example:

```
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date);
```

which outputs:

> Mon Jun 24 21:46:22 BST 2013

To convert to EDM format, do the following:

```
String firstPartOfPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
String secondPartOfPattern = "HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(firstPartOfPattern);
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat(secondPartOfPattern);
String formattedDate = sdf1.format(date) + "T" + sdf2.format(date);
```

`formattedDate` now has the following format:

> 2013-06-24T21:46:22

Comment: This Answer uses outdated troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As mentioned you shouldn't use `SimpleDateFormat` anymore in Java 8+!

You can do also simplify the steps described by Sam:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
```

Comment: This Answer uses outdated troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
myUtilDate.toInstant().toString()
```

> 2017-01-23T01:23:45.123Z

## ISO 8601

Your desired format is defined in the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing or generating strings.

## java.time

Avoid using the outdated troublesome old date-time classes such as `Date` that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Convert your `Date` object to java.time by using new methods added to the old classes. The modern counterpart to `Date` is `Instant` for a moment on the timeline in UTC but with a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = myUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

To generate your ISO 8601 string, simply call `toString`. The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means UTC.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

Comment: I have used the `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` formatter because I wanted to specify the timezone.

Comment: @coffeemakr Very well. You can also assign an offset by calling `instant.atOffset` to generate a `OffsetDateTime` object. Usually better to assign a time zone `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. A zone is a collection of past, present, and future changes in the offset used by the people of a particular region.