# Javascript Convert to EDM Date for OData

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, odata

How do I convert a Javascript date to EDM Date format for OData usage?

```
let currentDate = new Date();
// is there a native function to convert?
```

The following answers seem to use outdated answers, wondering if

Latest Javascript in ECMA 2020 have a native function to convert?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14405868/14727392

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17284978/14727392

**Resources:** https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/json-format/

Note: conducting work in Angular 10 framework

By the way, This function does not work in Angular giving error below,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14405868/14727392

```
function convertJSONDate(jsonDate, returnFormat) {
    var myDate = new Date(jsonDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
    myDate.add(4).hours();  //using {date.format.js} to add time to compensate for timezone offset
    return myDate.format(returnFormat); //using {date.format.js} plugin to format :: EDM FORMAT='yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss'
}
```

> Error: Property 'add' does not exist on type 'Date';  Property 'format' does not exist on type 'Date'

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: `date.toISOString()` should do, no?

Comment: hi @Bergi however I don't believe IsoString is in LocalDatetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but this is what I assume you are trying to achieve:

```js
const dateJSONToEDM = jsonDate => {
  const content = /\d+/.exec(String(jsonDate));
  const timestamp = content ? Number(content[0]) : 0;
  const date = new Date(timestamp);
  const string = date.toISOString();
  return string;
};

console.log(
  dateJSONToEDM(`/Date(1609195194804)/`)
); // Outputs "2020-12-28T22:39:54.804Z"
```